# how am I meant to get this video uploaded to rumble. It says "date is in the past"

Tags: upload

how am I meant to get this video uploaded to rumble. It says "date is in the past" but it's not the date/time is 2min into the future

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to check the "Schedule video" checkbox? Have you tried to uncheck it?

Comment: @Rubén thanks.. I thought i'd tried that before.. but I just tried that now (after Having uploaded it last night and waited ages/slept). And it worked.  You can post as an answer.. unticking that box.  You can post that as an answer

Comment: also next time I try to upload something i'll take a look at the upload button more closely.. did it appear more enabled or disabled.. do i have to wait a long time after it reaches 100% etc. But at least I have a method now.. thanks ruben